# Execute spark sql query on dataframe column values

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get the size of each table in my database.
I listed first all my tables in a dataframe using this command :

```
df = spark.sql("show tables in db")
```

And this is my current dataframe :

```
+---------+
| tabs    |
+---------+
|db.tab1  |
|db.tab2  |
|db.tab3  |
|db.tab4  |
|db.tab5  |
+---------+
```

Then, for each table I want to get some informations such as **count** and l**ast modification date**.
To explain more, what I want to do is something like this (*it's not working*) :

```
df1 = df.withColumn("count", spark.sql('select count(*) from {0}'.format(df.tabs)))
```

This is the desired result :

```
+---------+------+
| tabs    | count|
+---------+------+
|db.tab1  |  122 |
|db.tab2  |  156 |
|db.tab3  |  235 |
|db.tab4  |  11  |
|db.tab5  |  98  |
+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below.
get count for each table and union them.

```py
tables = df.collect()

count_dfs = [
  spark.sql(f'select {table} as tabs, count(*) as count from {table}')
  for table in tables
]

result_df = reduce(lambda union_dfs, count_df: union_dfs.union(count_df))
result_df.show()
```